# Get Custom plugin configuration details in Shopware.6.1

Tags: shopware, shopware6

how to get the custom plugin configuration details in 6.1 if 6.5 we can use config() function but in 6.1 it is not supported how to get in twig file or js file in store front

Answer (score 1):

For versions up to and including 6.3 see below.
To get a quick overview of available configs, it should also be possible to do `{{ dump(shopware) }}`.

For [plugin configuration](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/v6.3/guides/plugins/apps/configuration.html#reading-the-config-in-templates):
`{{ shopware.config.PluginName.config.fieldName }}`

For Shopware [core configuration](https://github.com/shopware/shopware/blob/01c209a305adaabaf894e6929290c69c4a07adef/src/Storefront/Resources/views/storefront/component/address/address-personal.html.twig#L113C23-L113C76):
`{{ shopware.config.core.settingGroup.settingField }}`

For theme configuration (located in src/Resources/theme.json):
`{{ shopware.theme['fieldName'] }}`

The `config()` and `theme_config()` methods are available for versions 6.4 and up